# Is Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite); more efficient than while(true){}?

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a console application that I would like to keep open all of the time while still listening in to events. I have tested `Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);` and `while (true) { }` and both allow the events to be raised while keeping the console application open. Is there one that I should be using over the other? If the thread is sleeping, is there anything that I should not be doing, such as modifying a static collection declared in the scope of the class?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I would recommend using a `ManualResetEvent` (or other `WaitHandle`), and calling [ManualResetEvent.WaitOne](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd.aspx).

This will have a similar effect to sleeping forever, except that it provides you a clean way to *exit* from your infinite "block" when desired (by calling [`Set()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.set.aspx) on the event).

Using `while(true)` will consume CPU cycles, so it's definitely something to avoid.

> is there anything that I should not be doing, such as modifying a static collection declared in the scope of the class?

In general, no.  Since your thread will be blocked, there shouldn't be any synchronization issues with using shared data (provided the items within the collection don't have specific requirements, such as user interface elements which must be used on a thread with a proper synchronization context.)

Comment: I actually don't want it to exit at all, but I will accept your answer in case that there are people looking that do wish to have a way to exit.

Comment: @Daniel It is nice to have a clean way for your program to shutdown *eventually*, even if that's not something you want at any specific point in time ;)  That being said, I'd still use this approach over a sleep, personally.

Comment: How would using using the ManualResetEvent differ with Thread.Sleep() if the only time that the program closes is when the machine restarts?

Comment: @Daniel I think that the intention is a bit more clear.  It's going to have the same effect

Comment: The ManualResetEvent option takes a few more characters and the intent is no clearer than "sleep for infinity", but it does *feel* less of a hack.

Comment: If you want asynchronously suspend code using Task indefinitely, my answer is better.

Comment: @ReedCopsey, can u give sample example code for this, ManualResetEvent vs while-loop true

Answer (score 24):

Since **C# 7.1**, you can make the *Main* method asynchronous. That means instead of using busy-wait or thread-locking sleeping, you can suspend the *Main* method asynchronously as a *Task*. This way, the thread which ran *Main* will not be locked. And with `Cts.Cancel()`, you can easily release the main task to exit the application (without allowing work for other threads/tasks to finish).

```
static readonly CancellationTokenSource Cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    /* your code here */

    // Task running Main is efficiently suspended (no CPU use) forever until Cts activated with Program.Cts.Cancel(); (thread-safe) from anywhere.
    await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, Cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Since **year 2020, C# 9.0**, the whole `Program.cs` file content can literally look exactly like this:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

CancellationTokenSource Cts = new();

/* your code here */

// Task running Main is efficiently suspended (no CPU use) forever until
// Cts activated with Program.Cts.Cancel(); (thread-safe) from anywhere.
await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, Cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

You can try-catch TaskCanceledException if infinite-sleep cancellation is normal codeflow for the case (please DON'T use `Task.Delay` *inf-sleep* when you are trying to await/sync with other Tasks, try-catch is less efficient and will confuse teammates; use other mechanisms for task cooperation):

```
try
{
    await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, Cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
catch(TaskCanceledException) { /* Ignored */ }
```

Comment: And how do you cancel/stop it?

Comment: `Cts.Cancel();` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancel?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_CancellationTokenSource_Cancel

Comment: It throws an exception

Answer (score 6):

I think the call

```
while (true) { ... }
```

is computationally intensive, since the thread never stops, wheareas

```
Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
```

actually gets the thread to sleep with help of OS native schedulers. And then the thread actually stops, so I suppose it's less computationally demanding.

Comment: There seems uncertainty in your answer... "I think", "I suppose", etc.

Comment: i was sure about the answer but i just started a career in java that is why i used "I think", "I suppose" for precaution. :)

Answer (score 5):

Unlike `while(true)...`, `Thread.Sleep` does not use CPU cycles, so in this sense, the sleep is more efficient. In general, using [Busy Waiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) outside of [spinlocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock) is strongly discouraged.

> If the thread is sleeping, is there anything that I should not be doing?

Since your thread is blocked upon entry to `Thread.Sleep`, anything that you wish to do to its resources is a fair game.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen the while loop being recommended to people trying to accomplish what I'm doing and I wasn't sure if that was the correct way to go about it.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, 
`while(true)` consumes CPU while `sleep()` works in a smarter way: 
The `sleep()` function puts the current execution context to sleep; it does this by calling a syscall to invoke the kernel sleep function which atomically
(a) sets a wake-up timer
(b) marks the current process as sleeping
(c) waits until the wakeup-timer fires or an interrupt occurs

If you call `sleep()`, the CPU can do other work.

That's one reason why `sleep()` is useful.

A useful link - [Be careful when using Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> Calling the Thread.Sleep method causes the current thread to immediately block for the number of milliseconds or the time interval you pass to the method, and yields the remainder of its time slice to another thread.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/pausing-and-resuming-threads?redirectedfrom=MSDN#the-threadsleep-method