# Control lifetime of .NET Core console application hosted in docker

Tags: c#, linux, docker, servicestack, .net-core

Disclaimer - this is almost the same question as [docker container exits immediately even with Console.ReadLine() in a .net core console application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38549006/685341) - but I don't think accepted answer on this question is satisfactory.

**What I am trying to achieve**
I am building a console application (it is a HTTP service using ServiceStack) which is built with .NET core (dnxcore50 - this is a console app, not an ASP.NET application). I am running this application in a docker container on a Linux machine. This I have done, and the HTTP service works.

**My problem**
Having said that 'my service works' - and it does, there is a problem hosting the service in a docker container. I am using `Console.ReadLine()` after starting up my HTTP listener, but this code does not block within the docker container and the container will exit immediately after starting. I can start the docker container in 'interactive' mode, and the service will sit there listening until I kill the interactive session and then the container will exit.

**Code for Repo**
The code below is a complete code listing for creating my test .NET core servicestack console application.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new AppHost().Init().Start("http://*:8088/");
        Console.WriteLine("listening on port 8088");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}

public class AppHost : AppSelfHostBase
{
    // Initializes your AppHost Instance, with the Service Name and assembly containing the Services
    public AppHost() : base("My Test Service", typeof(MyTestService).GetAssembly()) { }

    // Configure your AppHost with the necessary configuration and dependencies your App needs
    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {

    }
}

public class MyTestService: Service
{
    public TestResponse Any(TestRequest request)
    {
        string message = string.Format("Hello {0}", request.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        return new TestResponse {Message = message};
    }

}

[Api("Test method")]
[Route("/test/{Name}", "GET", Summary = "Get Message", Notes = "Gets a message incorporating the passed in name")]
public class TestRequest : IReturn<TestResponse>
{
    [ApiMember(Name = "Name", Description = "Your Name", ParameterType = "path", DataType = "string")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TestResponse 
{
    [ApiMember(Name = "Message", Description = "A Message", ParameterType = "path", DataType = "string")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

**The old way of solving this problem**
So having previously hosted using Mono (Mono had severe performance issues - hence the switch to .NET core) - the way to fix this behaviour was to use `Mono.Posix` listen for a kill signal like this:

```
using Mono.Unix;
using Mono.Unix.Native;

...

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Start your service here...

        // check if we're running on mono
        if (Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime") != null)
        {
            // on mono, processes will usually run as daemons - this allows you to listen
            // for termination signals (ctrl+c, shutdown, etc) and finalize correctly
            UnixSignal.WaitAny(new[] {
                new UnixSignal(Signum.SIGINT),
                new UnixSignal(Signum.SIGTERM),
                new UnixSignal(Signum.SIGQUIT),
                new UnixSignal(Signum.SIGHUP)
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Now - I understand that this won't work for .NET Core (obviously because Mono.Posix is for Mono!)

The solution outlined in the related article (top of this post) is no use to me - in a production environment, I can't expect to keep a docker container alive by ensuring it has an interactive session available which will keep the Console.ReadLine working because there is a STD-IN stream there...

Is there another way to keep my docker container alive (using the `-d` (detached) option when invoking `docker run`) when hosting a .NET Core application?

**Code refactor as part of Mythz suggestion**

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Run(new AppHost().Init(), "http://*:8088/");
    }

    public static void Run(ServiceStackHost host, params string[] uris)
    {
        AppSelfHostBase appSelfHostBase = (AppSelfHostBase)host;

        using (IWebHost webHost = appSelfHostBase.ConfigureHost(new WebHostBuilder(), uris).Build())
        {
            ManualResetEventSlim done = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
            using (CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
            {
                Action shutdown = () =>
                {
                    if (!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Application is shutting down...");
                        cts.Cancel();
                    }

                    done.Wait();
                };

                Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, eventArgs) =>
                {
                    shutdown();
                    // Don't terminate the process immediately, wait for the Main thread to exit gracefully.
                    eventArgs.Cancel = true;
                };

                Console.WriteLine("Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.");
                webHost.Run(cts.Token);
                done.Set();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Final Solution!**

For Posterity - the solution I have gone with is the code which can be found here (Thanks to Myths for clarification): https://github.com/NetCoreApps/Hello/blob/master/src/SelfHost/Program.cs

Repo of the pertinent code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseUrls("http://*:8088/")
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseServiceStack(new AppHost());

        app.Run(context =>
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/metadata");
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        });
    }
```

In NuGet, I have Microsoft.NETCore.App, ServiceStack.Core and ServiceStack.Kestrel installed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're going to host .NET Core apps in Docker I'd recommend just following the normal [.NET Core Hosting API](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v4.5.2#binding-to-net-core) where it calls `IWebHost.Run()` to block the main thread and keep the Console Application alive.

AppHostSelfBase is just a [wrapper around .NET Core's hosting API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/86e34f203dea3c8676ec37f1e64a7b5778d749af/src/ServiceStack.Kestrel/AppSelfHostBase.cs#L118) but calls the non-blocking `IWebHost.Start()` instead. To get the behavior of `IWebHost.Run()` you should be able to reuse the same approach of `ManualResetEventSlim` and `Console.CancelKeyPress` that [WebHost.Run()'s implementation uses](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/WebHostExtensions.cs#L21), but personally it's just easier to use .NET Core's Hosting API and call `Run()` and just [register your ServiceStack AppHost as a .NET Core module](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v4.5.2#net-core-startup).

Comment: I've had a go at using the code as (I think) you have suggested - it appears to work in both Windows and in my Linux Docker... the update is to my original question - at the bottom of the post. What do you think of the solution? Have I understood you correctly?

Comment: @Jay if it works I'm sure it's fine, but why not use .NET Core's recommended hosting model? It's not clear why you'd want to maintain your own implementation.

Comment: Possibly because I don't understand it yet :) I'm a complete noob to .NET core and really don't understand how the example here: http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v4.5.2.html#apphostbase-net-core-module will work in Linux; i.e. what does `UseIISIntegration()` do in a Linux container, and how do I set the port I want to listen on. I'm so used to creating simple self hosted console apps using ServiceStack - that I wanted something that worked pretty much the same as before. Maybe I need to do a bit more reading about .NET core and the hosting model.

Comment: @Jay All apps in .NET Core are self-hosting Console Apps and UseIISIntegration() is ignored on Linux so you can ignore/remove it. You don't need to understand .NET Core hosting model, just leave it as-is, the main thing it does is point to your custom Startup class and listen on the URL you specify. Have a look at the existing .NET Core Live Demos at https://github.com/NetCoreApps which contain small stand alone examples of ServiceStack's existing Live Demos.

Comment: @Jay also each of the .NET Core examples run as-is on Windows and Linux. They're all hosted on Linux/Docker and deployed with AWS ECS using the deploy scripts contained in each repo as documented in this step-by-step guide: http://docs.servicestack.net/deploy-netcore-docker-aws-ecs

Comment: Found exactly what I needed in the sample files - I've linked to the git source repository and updated the original question. You are right; so much cleaner using the WebHostBuilder. I think I understand now! :)

Comment: @Jay Great, Happy to hear it :) also you don't need the ServiceStack.Kestrel NuGet package anymore as it just wraps Kestrel within the AppSelfHostBase class which you're no longer using.